# Use selectors from jQuery or JavaScript in this project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors, getelementbyid

I'm  making a project that includes a lot of elements creation and appending, after a little research i came up with that

`$(newElement)` and `$(selector)`

are slower than

`.createElement(newElement)` and `.getElementBy`

Since i'm doing a todo-list app which will include a lot of creation/appending/selection of this :

```
<div class="mainTaskWrapper clearfix">
    <div class="mainMarker"></div>
    <label for="task1">This is task1</label>
    <div class="holder"></div>
    <div class="subTrigger"></div>                            
    <div class="checkButton"></div>
    <div class="optTrigger"></div>
    <div class="mainOptions">
        <ul>
            <li id="mainInfo">Details</li>
            <li id="mainDivide">Divide</li>
            <li id="mainEdit">Edit</li>
            <li id="mainDelete">Delete</li>
        </ul>                               
    </div>
</div>
```

What would you advise me to use ? jQuery selection and creation way, or JavaScript one ?

Comment: Gee whiz, jQuery is slower than plain JS, who would have thought ?

Comment: I would suggest http://vanilla-js.com/ framework, but maybe jQuery if you are not fluent in VanillaJS.

Comment: Try both in http://jsperf.com/ and see if the speed difference is worth the added code complexity.

Comment: I have a rich webapp that has a ton of JS interaction and uses jQuery for pretty much everything.  There has never been a noticeable performance problem for me for any operation.  Unless your DOM is enormous, I don't think you will have much of a problem with jQuery.  It's up to you to benchmark, though.

Comment: @RichardDalton jsperf gives you performance rankings for thousands of iterations of your code. Necessary for the test, but if your code is only being iterated once or a handful of time, this kind of optimization is meaningless.

Comment: hahah that vanillaJS website cracks me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "a lot of creation/appending/selection", what exactly do you mean?

Is it in the order of several per second, or just "a lot"? Since the code will run client-side, one per second won't be that much of an issue.

jQuery would then be the 'best' choice, as maintainability is a large plus, and any code you write with jQuery will probably be a lot clearer.

Comment: Well, when the user press a certain button the code above gets created and appended to its parent div. It depends on user interaction.

Comment: Then, (IMHO,) you shouldn't worry too much about the added complexity of jQuery. It might be 'slower', but most likely on a scale of milliseconds. It's probably not worth the extra development time of using plain JS.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a bit on what else you're doing.  In some cases, setting innerHTML is the fastest (esp. with big bulky blocks getting inserted).

That said from a dev standpoint the jquery method is really the most maintainable.  I'd probably go w/ the jquery version until performance becomes a problem, and wrap the calls to jquery in other functions that I can swap out when it does.

Answer (score 1):

It's really a developer preference issue.

Personally, I find strictly using jQuery selectors to be easier to write and understand, and more consistent when the selectors get more complex.  Using native JavaScript is faster to compile and render, but you might not actually see any difference depending on the complexity of your page.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you NOT to create that many identical elements all at once. Instead, place them once in your HTML and hide it (use `display:none`) and then use jQuery to `.clone()` the whole block as needed.

HOWEVER: First, get rid of those `id=` attributes. You can't have more than one element on a page with the same ID.